# How can i connect with mongodb in SlamData for my EC2 server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, slamdata

I can successfully connected with mongodb on SlamData but for my localhost. Now I have a mongodb database on my EC2 server that database i want to connect in Ec2 then How can I ?

[image]

I know username and password. What should be a host and port?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Slamdata on your host and want to connect to MongoDB running on a remote EC2 host.

Then apart from the username and password, the host is the Public IP or host FQDN [ec2-xxxxxxx], port is 27017. For this check if your mongos is running and binding on 0.0.0.0. If it is binding to 127.0.0.1, you cannot connect remotely

Also check you AWS security group for EC2 and see that the port 27017 is open for your IP or in general to all [0.0.0.0] (this is NOT recommended!!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can also review the FAQ on docs.slamdata.com located [here](http://docs.slamdata.com/en/latest/troubleshooting-faq.html#slamdata-on-amazon-ec2-microsoft-azure-etc).

Provides step-by-step troubleshooting for connecting to cloud-hosted MongoDB servers.

Additionally, the **Path** value refers to path inside of SlamData rather than the operating system path.  For instance entering a value of *aws1* results in a query path similar to the following, assuming you have a databased named *demo* and a collection named *coll1*:

> SELECT * FROM `/aws1/demo/coll1`